# Using Virtual Page Views in Javascript Overlay

Tags: javascript

I added a couple lines of code to my custom.js that do not run properly in a conversion funnel report using virtual page views.

I would like two virtual page views to run;

hj('vpv', '/sign-up/'); when the overlay contact form is generated
and

hj('vpv', '/thank-you/'); when the form is submitted

I am either off on the placement or missing something.

http://inside.hotjar.com/support/solutions/articles/1000125864

```js
function showEarlyAccessForm(){
    "use strict";
    $('.modal-title').html('Commercial Inquires');
    $('.modal-subtitle').html('The Safest & Most Effective Traction Agent');

    $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger').html('');
}

function openEarlyAccessModal(){
    "use strict";
    showEarlyAccessForm();
    $('#loginModal').modal('show');
    hj('vpv', '/sign-up/');
}

$(function() {
    $('#earlyaccess-modal').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "assets/php/constantcontact.php",
            data: {
                'lm-first-name': $('#lm-first-name').val(),
                'lm-email': $('#lm-email').val(),
                'lm-phone': $('#lm-phone').val(),
                'lm-company': $('#lm-company').val(),
                'lm-comments': $('#lm-comments').val()
            },
            success: function(resp){
                $('.lm-success')
                .html('<i class="icon icon_check_alt2"></i>' + ' Thank you')
                .fadeIn(1000);

                $('.lm-failed').fadeOut(500);
                
                hj('vpv','/thank-you/');

                // Track conversion
                var google_conversion_id = 961104703;
                var google_conversion_language = "en";
                var google_conversion_format = "2";
                var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
                var google_conversion_label = "TQRYCKjUnlkQv5alygM";
                var google_remarketing_only = false;
                $.getScript( "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js" );

            },
            error: function(resp){
                $('.lm-failed')
                .html('<i class="icon icon_close_alt2"></i>')
                .fadeIn(1000);

                $('.lm-success').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It appears that this script is indeed working, there was just seems to have been a lag between when I implemented the code and the reporting on hj.

Comment: The Hotjar funnels are updated every hour, so you're absolutely correct that there's a small lag present between the virtual page view occurring and the admin getting updated.

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the Hotjar developers)